# Creating correct concrete type from database read

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class

A project I'm working on would benefit from having a little more abstraction added to it and I'm faced with a problem I can't seem to get past.

Essentially is we have services that can be assigned and consumed, but the rates at which they are consumed are all a little different. This distinction is important for reporting and for scheduling the consumption of these services.

I'm not really sure how to take data I receive from the database and ensure that the correct concrete type is created. Am I overthinking this and there is something easier I can do? The only thing I can think of doing is having a switch statement determine which type to make based on the unit of time specified, but that seems sloppy.

UnitInterval (which I'm welcome to renaming it something that seems less confusing), is supposed to hold the service's consumption unit (1, 15, 30, 60) and then the UnitSize will be minutes, hours, or days. The UnitSizes are held in a reference table and ID'ed with their appropriate text of Day, Minute, Hour. So in my table Minute has an ID = 1, Hour = 2, Day = 3, and depending on if these intervals need to be adjusted they can be in the future.

How do I get something like the UnitSize from the database and ensure the correct implementation? Am I just going about this the entirely wrong way?

Essentially my end game is that I'll have another class which just contains `List<WorkableService>` that I can use to spit out a report with the correct units, any costing, duration, etc.

```
public abstract class WorkableService
{
    public int UnitSizeId { get; set; }
    public string UnitSizeText { get; set; } 

    public double UnitInterval { get; set; }
    public abstract TimeSpan Duration { get; }
    public double UnitsAvailable { get; set; }
    public double Adjustment { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}

public class MinuteService : WorkableService
{
    public override TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        { 
            return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(UnitInterval); 
        }
    }
}

public class HourlyService : WorkableService
{
    public override TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get 
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromHours(UnitInterval);        
        }
    }
}

public class DailyService : WorkableService
{
    public override TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get 
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromDays(UnitInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch statement you refer to as sloppy is something called the Factory pattern.  Assuming your `WorkableService` base constructor takes `UnitInterval`:

```
static class WorkableServiceFactory
{
    public static WorkableService Get(int unitSizeId, double unitInterval)
    {
        switch (unitSizeId)
        {
            case 1:
                return new MinuteService(unitInterval);
            case 2:
                return new HourlyService(unitInterval);
            case 3:
                return new DailyService(unitInterval);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("unitSizeId");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm usually not a fan of factories (they're the butt of every Java EE joke in the book for a reason), but this is actually a valid scenario for it.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at the Factory pattern earlier today, and since there are only so many units of time, I think it's easy to control the creation. I can't see the concrete classes being too out of control or growing much, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

The switch method is totally valid, if you know for sure at compile time all the options you might need. More basic info at the Wikipedia  [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), but switching on an enum value or a string identifier is the general concept.

Alternatively, look into [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can use to create a new object based on the type's name that you might dynamically load from the database. We do that in some situations to let us add new supported types without recompiling the base service.